# How to track object using dlib(c++) from video stream passed from darknet(c)?

Tags: opencv, tracking, object-detection, dlib, darknet

I am using darknet to detect objects from live video stream and want to pass each frame to dlib for tracking that object but i'm confused that how i pass frames from darknet's [demo.c](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/src/demo.c) to dlib and do the tracking.
Do i need to use c c++ connector ? if yes, how? any explanation or clues would be helpful.
thanks...

Dlib file where i want to pass ipl image and want to track the object.

```
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <dlib/dir_nav.h>
#include "dlib/opencv.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

extern "C"{

int enx = 203, int eny = 190, int enw = 98, int enh = 86;

void track(IplImage  * ipl, int enx, int eny, int enw, int enh)
{
    Mat frame = cvarrToMat(ipl);
    image_window win;
    correlation_tracker tracker;
    array2d<rgb_pixel> img;

    std::cout << "Starting" << std::endl;
    assign_image(img, cv_image<bgr_pixel>(frame));
    tracker.start_track(img, centered_rect(point(enx, eny), enw, enh));

    win.set_image(img); 
    win.clear_overlay(); 
    win.add_overlay(tracker.get_position());

    while(ipl) {
        Mat frame = cvarrToMat(ipl);
        assign_image(img, cv_image<bgr_pixel>(frame));
        tracker.update(img);
        win.set_image(img); 
        win.clear_overlay(); 
        win.add_overlay(tracker.get_position());
    }    
}
}
```

Comment: Use any of the ported darknets to c++

Comment: i can't use ported darknet

Comment: Then you'll have to port it yourself. Or use dlib's dnn object detector.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to look at https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/yolo_console_dll.cpp 
where you will find many ideas about darknet data manipulation. Including tracker

Comment: thanks for the answer @szhernovoy , it's really useful.